# Template function for STL iterators, pointers and std::nullptr_t

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a wrapper around a c-based API function. 
The user should be able to pass RandomAccessIterators, pointers or the nullptr as parameters to the wrapper function.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Iter>
constexpr bool is_random_access_iterator_v = std::is_convertible_v<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category, std::random_access_iterator_tag>;

template <typename Iter>
using iterater_decayed_type_t = std::decay_t<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>;

// convert iterator to pointer
template <typename Iter>
auto get_pointer(Iter it) {
    if constexpr (std::is_null_pointer_v<Iter> || std::is_pointer_v<Iter>) {
        return it;
    } else {
        return &*it;
    }
}

// InputIter and OutputIter can be arbitrary iterator or pointer. 
// OutputIter can also be a nullptr
template <typename InputIter, typename OutputIter>
OutputIter wrapper(InputIter first, InputIter last, OutputIter d_first) {
    static_assert(is_random_access_iterator_v<InputIter>, "InputIter needs to be a RandomAccessIterator");
    static_assert(std::is_null_pointer_v<OutputIter> || is_random_access_iterator_v<OutputIter>, "OutputIter needs to be a RandomAccessIterator or nullptr");
    static_assert(std::is_null_pointer_v<OutputIter> || std::is_same_v<iterater_decayed_type_t<InputIter>, iterater_decayed_type_t<OutputIter>>, "Iterator value types must be identical or OutputIter is nullptr");

    using value_t = iterater_decayed_type_t<InputIter>;

    using first_ptr_t = typename std::iterator_traits<InputIter>::pointer;
    first_ptr_t ptr_first = get_pointer(first);

    using d_first_ptr_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_null_pointer_v<OutputIter>, std::nullptr_t, typename std::iterator_traits<OutputIter>::pointer>;
    d_first_ptr_t ptr_d_first = get_pointer(d_first);

    // func gets arbitrary pointers (void*)
    func(ptr_first, ptr_d_first, last - first);
    return d_first;
}
```

This code doesn't compile because `std::iterator_traits<T>` isn't specialized for `std::nullptr_t`.

I already came up with two possible solutions:

1.) Specialize `std::iterator_traits<std::nullptr_t>`, e.g.:

```
namespace std {
    template <>
    struct iterator_traits<std::nullptr_t> {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = std::nullptr_t;
        using pointer = std::nullptr_t;
        using reference = std::nullptr_t;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_concept = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}
```

But as far as I know specializing stl namespace members can quickly lead to undefined behavior.

2.) Split the functionality in two functions. The problem here is that it would lead to unnecessary copy-paste code. Additionally I want to add several overloads to the original function which would lead to two times the number of functions at the end (e.g. for 4 normal overloads I would require 8 overloads with this approach).

So my question is: 
Is there any way to solve this problem by **not** introducing possible undefined behavior and having to create two times the number of overloaded functions? 
For example tweaking the `is_random_access_iterator_v` trait to not rely on `std::iterator_traits`?

Comment: Not related to your question at hand, but your function seems to assume that an iterator being random access implies its elements are stored contiguously.  This is not the case.  For instance, `std::deque::iterator` is a random access iterator, but the elements of a `std::deque` are not stored contiguously.

Comment: @Miles Budnek I know but std::contiguous_iterator_tag isn't available in GCC 9.2 yet (or at least I was not able to get it working)

Comment: Random access iterators are not guaranteed to be isomprphic to pointers into a C-style array (see std::deque). The whole wrapping operation is highly dubious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specialize `std::iterator_traits<std::nullptr_t>`, but you can create your own traits:

```
template <typename T>
struct my_iterator_traits : iterator_traits<T> {};

template <>
struct my_iterator_traits<std::nullptr_t>
{
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = std::nullptr_t;
    using pointer = std::nullptr_t;
    using reference = std::nullptr_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
};
```

and use `my_iterator_traits` for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I thought you should inherit from STL classes (e.g. std::vector because of the lacking virtual destructor), but std::iterator_traits is just a bunch of typedefs so perfectly fine.